# Templating data in HTML

Tags: templating

I have an Matrix field and I want to extract data in the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="row">
  <div><p>text1</p><img src="{{imgurl1}}" /></div>
  <div><p>text2</p><img src="{{imgurl2}}" /></div>
  <div><p>text3</p><img src="{{imgurl3}}" /></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div><p>text4</p><img src="{{imgurl4}}" /></div>
  <div><p>text5</p><img src="{{imgurl5}}" /></div>
  <div><p>text6</p><img src="{{imgurl6}}" /></div>
</div>
```

and this is my twig code for retrieving data from craft:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
  {% if loop.index is divisible by(3) %}
     <div class="row">
  <div><p>text4</p><img src="{{imgurl4}}" /></div>
  <div><p>text5</p><img src="{{imgurl5}}" /></div>
  <div><p>text6</p><img src="{{imgurl6}}" /></div>
</div>
{% else %}
 <div><p>text4</p><img src="{{imgurl4}}" /></div>
  <div><p>text5</p><img src="{{imgurl5}}" /></div>
  <div><p>text6</p><img src="{{imgurl6}}" /></div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to output multiple browse with free divs
I am new to Craft and I will appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you really wanted dynamic variable names like `imgurl1` or not, but something like this?

```
<div class="row">
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% set loopIndex = loop.index %}
    <div><p>text{{loopIndex}}</p><img src="{{ _context['imgurl' ~ loopIndex] }}" /></div>
    {% if loopIndex is divisible by(3) %}
        {% if not loop.last %}
            </div>
            <div class="row">
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: yes, it displays the correct HTML structure, thank you very much for your help.